# Is it possible to write a PLC Ladder program in, say, C++?

Tags: c++, arduino, plc

I need to program an Arduino Uno in order to control an industrial fan. Currently, this fan is controlled by a Schneider PLC. This PLC has installed a very simple (it does not even have a watch) but lengthy Ladder program. I want to rewrite the code in the classical "imperative code style" (see the example below) but, since the program is so long, this work is very time-consuming. Then, my question is if there is a software that can do the job.

**An example**: if in Ladder I have something like

```
           |---- R1 --- |
   --|In|--|            |---------|Out|--
           |---- R2 --- |
```

then I would like to have the "imperative code" (I wrote it in pseudocode, but any language, like C++ or Python, is OK):

```
  Do loop:
    In = "logical value of the cable connected to input In"
    Out = In and (R1 or R2)
```

Comment: I never saw anything like that... The only thing I know is a program to code in ladder and compile to c++. Take a look on [this](https://www.open-electronics.org/arduino-as-a-programmable-logic-controller-plc/) site.

Comment: why I have -1 point? the -1's person should explain at least

Comment: so you want to flash the PLC with c++?? or replace the PLC with an Arduino?